# Calling external api from node js with multipart/form-data

Tags: node.js

Iam using request() in node js to call external apis.

```
    if (req.method == 'GET')
    options.qs = req.query;
else
    options.form = req.body;

request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error || [constants.response_codes.success, constants.response_codes.internal_server_error, constants.response_codes.error, constants.response_codes.unauthorized].indexOf(response.statusCode) < 0) return next(true);
    return next(null, { statuscode: response.statusCode, data: response.body });
});
```

It is working with req.method GET,POST,PUT and DELETE.But I need to send multipart/form-data for sending files from the client side to laravel project via node js.Iam using body-parser in node js for parsing the request.How can it be achieved by using request() in node js to send file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
const options = {
    method: "POST",
    url: "Your URL",
    port: 443,
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + auth,
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    },
    formData : {
        "image" : fs.createReadStream("./images/src.png")
    }
};

request(options, function (err, res, body) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: The file is uploaded from the client side using angular js.So I need to parse the file using multer library ,so that only i can save it in images directory and send using "image" : fs.createReadStream("./images/src.png").Is any other solution to send file without saving in node js .